# how to resolve npm install -g cordova ionic npm ERR! registry error parsing json?

Tags: android, json, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

i am trying to install Cordova and ionic on my machine but when i type below command it gives me following error-

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v7.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9

npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
npm ERR! <HTML>
npm ERR! <Head>
npm ERR! <TITLE>404 Not Found
npm ERR! </TITLE>
npm ERR! </HEAD>
npm ERR! <BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><h1>
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! </h1>
npm ERR! </BODY>
npm ERR! </HTML>
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     

npm-debug.log`enter code here`
```

how to resolve this issue ? please help.

Comment: Try to run npm cache clean and after that again npm install -g cordova ionic

Comment: What do you get if you run `npm config get registry`?

Comment: @JoeClay i get this -
>npm config get registry

http://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: @geo I have tried it many time but failed :(

Comment: Run `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`, then try to install again.

Comment: @JoeClay i have tried that already...doesnt work. same error again

Comment: npm install npm -g , npm cache clean and npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"